# Derivative of an integral function using FTC

Tags: calculus

> Compute the derivative of
>   $$\int_0^{\tan(x)}\sqrt{t+\sqrt{t}}\, dt.$$

Tried looking up a similar problem and found the apparent answer is $$\sqrt{\tan(x)+\sqrt{\tan(x)}}\cdot\sec^2(x).$$
But i'm not seeing how this answer was reached. Shouldn't it be $$\sqrt{\tan(x)+\sqrt{\tan(x)}}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{\tan(x)+\sqrt{\tan(x)}}?$$
How does $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{\tan(x)+\sqrt{\tan(x)}}$ becomes just $\sec^2(x)$?, shouldn't there be fractions involved due to the use of the power rule?

Answer (score 2):

By the fundamental theorem if we denote $g(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\text{d}t$ then
$$g'(x)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \int_a^xf(t)\text{d}t=f(x)$$
Now it becomes a problem of using the chain rule
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}g(\tan x) = g'(\tan x) \tan'(x)=f(\tan x)\sec^2x$$

Answer (score 0):

You should get $\sqrt{\tan x+\sqrt{\tan x}}\cdot \sec^2 x$, by FTC and the chain rule.  With practice you can do these by inspection.

No fractions because no power rule, because FTC says $(\int_c^xf(t)\operatorname dt)'=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to pretend you know an antiderivative for the integrand. Say $F(x)$ is a function such that $F'(x) = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}.$  Then you could evaluate your integral like this:

$$\int_0^{\tan x} \sqrt{t+\sqrt{t}} \; dt = F(\tan(x)) -F(0).$$

You want the derivative of this so you have

$$\frac{d}{dx} (F(\tan(x)) -F(0) ) = F'(\tan x) \frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan x)\right) -0 $$

$$=\sqrt{\tan x +\sqrt{\tan x}} \sec^2 x.$$